# How do I retain row-and-column arrangement while performing regular expression manipulations in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python and scripting.

I have a huge csv file of a table with 12 columns and thousands of rows that looks like this in Excel (note the 5 consecutive pipe signs indicate a new cell, so this example consists of three rows and three columns):

G",'32','0','0.98%',"1E0     |||||       G", '32', '0', '1%', "1E0  ||||| A", '48', '47', '97.92%', "7.6145E-27

G", '32', '0', '12%', "1E0 |||||    G", '32', '0', '3%', "1E0 ||||| A", '1', '47', '97.9%', "7.6145E-27

G", '32', '0', '0%', "1E0 ||||| G", '32', '32', '0%', "1E0 |||||    A", '1', '47', '9.92%', "7.6145E-27

As can be seen, each cell consists of five comma-delimited elements. I am only interested in the penultimate element (the one with a percentage value). Note how this value can either have decimals or not. So this is the code I wrote to search for that fourth element and write it to a new file in which the other elements are discarded.

```
import sys
import csv
import re

with open(sys.argv[1],"r") as f_input:
   read_f_input = csv.reader(f_input, delimiter=',')
   with open("f_output.csv", "wt") as f_output:
      f_outputwriter=csv.writer(f_output, delimiter=',')
      for row in read_f_input:
         genotype = re.search(r"[\d+\.]+%", [row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8], row[9], row[10], row[11]])
         result= genotype.group(0)
         f_outputwriter.writerow([result])
```

This script doesn't work because of the third-but-last line: genotype = ...
I have gotten the script to work if I only do this on a single column (ignoring the other 11 columns), but I want to perform the regular expression manipulation simultaneously on all 12 columns and write the result in the same table format. Does anyone know how I can do this tricky transformation? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The problem is that the lines do not keep the CSV rules.  On the other hand they are quite regular.  You can `line.split('|||||')` to get the cell strings.  Then you can parse each cell separately.  However, if the task is to separate all values with the percent signs (independently on their position), then see my solution below.

Comment: @Frank: Both pepr and kindall are really saying that you don't need to resort to regular expressions due to the fact that your percentages are always in the same position. Further, when pepr says the lines don't keep the CSV rules, he is referring to the fact that your data is showing up all messed up in Excel. I realize you have already marked his answer as accepted, but if you would open your CSV in Notepad and post the first few lines, an easier way to parse the data will probably become apparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the numbers are always bound with the percent sign, you can use `re.findall()` to get the list of the elements:

```
import csv
import re

fnamein = 'data.csv'
fnameout = 'output.csv'
rex = re.compile(r"'(\d*\.?\d*)%")  # an int/float element with percent sign

with open(fnamein, 'r') as fin, open(fnameout, 'w', newline='') as fout:
    writer = csv.writer(fout)
    for line in fin:
        row = rex.findall(line)         # all elements with percent sign
        row2 = [float(e) for e in row]  # converted explicitly if needed
        writer.writerow(row2)           # write to the output CSV
```

If the `data.csv` contained the lines from the question, the `output.csv` contains the following result:

```
0.98,1.0,97.92
12.0,3.0,97.9
0.0,0.0,9.92
```

This is for Python 3.  For Python 2, use `open(fnameout, 'wb')` for opening the output file (i.e. binary mode and no `newline`).

[Edited later] The `rex` is the compiled regular expression where the number before the percent sign forms a group -- see the parentheses around `(\d*\.?\d)*`.  The [doc](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/re.html#re.findall) says:

> If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups...

Because of that the `rex.findall()` returns the numbers that are followed by the percent sign, but not the percent sign itself.  In other words, the `row` contains the numbers as string literals (i.e. string representation of the numbers), but percent signs are not there.

The `row2 = [float(e) for e in row]` takes string representations of the numbers in the `row` and converts each element `e` to the float number (i.e. from a string to the real number).

The `writer` takes the floats and converts them to strings, separates the substring by commas, and writes them to the file.

Comment: Thank you very much, pepr, this is the answer I needed. I still don't know how you made it work (for instance I don't understand how row2 = [float(e) for e in row] makes the number appear without the percentage sign), but I'll make sure I read up on it.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the data you want just `row[3]`, `row[7]`, and `row[11]`? It seems you *already know* what columns you want, since all the rows are the same, so there's no need to try to find the desired columns using a regex. Also, of course, a regular expression won't search a list, so you'd have to join those back into a string, but in that case, why use the CSV reader to split it up when you're just going to join it back to search it? In short, I don't see what the regular expression has to do with your stated goal, and I believe you may be overthinking it.

Comment: Hi Kindall, thanks a lot for your input. I am learning a lot. So it seems that the CSV reader is superfluous for my task. I am still confused why I should only aim at row[3], row[7] and row[11]. I have 11 columns and want the percentage number in all of them displayed, not only in the 4th, 8th and 12th column. Doesn't the "row[3]" refer to the fourth column rather than the fourth element within a column?

Comment: I was going by the example you posted, where the percentage is always in the same column. If it can be in different columns, then the regex may be appropriate (though there could be better ways too).

Comment: @Frank: I think kindall has interpreted your 3-column example as your whole data, but you said your whole data has 12 columns, which has kind of tripped him up. If I'm following kindall's thinking, he interpreted each of your inner values as its own column, so your example would have 15 columns, and you would be selecting the 4th, 9th, and 14th columns (or 3, 8, and 13 by index number).

Comment: @JohnY: The data he posted *does* have 12 columns since he's using the CSV reader (and splitting on commas).

Comment: @kindall: No, it doesn't. If you consider his example literally (which I don't think is right, but anyway), you get **13** comma-separated values per row. If you consider his example the way he *explained* it, which is that he opened it in Excel, and he is personally inserting the quintuple-pipes to show us where *Excel* is breaking the columns, then you get three columns, where each column has five values (as he also explained in his question), or 15 total values per row, if you "flatten" the rows.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you've found a solution that you like, but I wrote the code below in about 10 minutes. You should be able to run it right out of the box, as follows:

python process_data.py --file=data.txt

**Output**

G",'32','0','1.960000.2%',"1E0 ||||| G", '32', '0','2.000000.2%', "1E0 ||||| A", '48', '47','195.840000.2%', "7.6145E-27
G", '32', '0','24.000000.2%', "1E0 ||||| G", '32', '0','6.000000.2%', "1E0 ||||| A", '1', '47','195.800000.2%', "7.6145E-27
G", '32', '0','0.000000.2%', "1E0 ||||| G", '32', '32','0.000000.2%', "1E0 ||||| A", '1', '47','19.840000.2%', "7.6145E-27

I just print the code out, but you could easily use csv.writer or file.writeline as you iterate over each line. The great thing about the code below is that it doesn't matter how many cells you have on a line as long as you know the cell delimiter and the position of the value that you want you can place as many cells as you like on a single row.

Removing the % is a bit of a hack, but if you know the data format then you should be safe. You could also throw an exception block around the conversion to float() and keep track of how many errors that you run encounter.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os, sys, pdb, re
# NOTE: This has been deprecated you should use ArgumentParser
from optparse import OptionParser

__version__ = '$Id$'

DEFAULT_CELL_SEP = '|||||'
DEFAULT_CELL_COL_SEP = ','

parser = OptionParser(version=__version__, usage='Usage: %prog --fille=data_file [--      csep=cell_seperator --ccsep=cell_col_seperator]')
parser.add_option('-f','--file',dest='data_file', 
              help='File to process')
parser.add_option('--csep',dest='cell_sep', default=DEFAULT_CELL_SEP,
              help='Cell Separator')
parser.add_option('--ccseip', dest='cell_col_sep', default=DEFAULT_CELL_COL_SEP,
              help='Column Separator for each cell')

def process_col_four(cell, cell_col_sep=DEFAULT_CELL_COL_SEP, suffix='%'):
    cols = cell.split(cell_col_sep)
    # Do what you need to do...
    # pdb.set_trace()
    col_4 = cols[3].replace(' ','')
    col_4 = float(col_4[1:-2])
    col_4 = col_4 *2
    cols[3] = "'%f.2%s'" % (col_4, suffix)
    return ','.join(cols)
    # return cols

def main(data_file, cell_sep=DEFAULT_CELL_SEP, cell_col_sep=DEFAULT_CELL_COL_SEP):
    data_dir = os.path.dirname(data_file)
    output_file, ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(data_file))
    output_file = output_file + '_recode' + ext
    output_path = os.path.join(data_dir, output_file)

    with open(data_file, 'r') as data_reader:
        for line in data_reader:
            cells = line.strip().split(cell_sep)
             new_cells = map(process_col_four, cells)
             # pdb.set_trace()
             new_line = cell_sep.join([cell for cell in new_cells])
             print new_line


if __name__ == '__main__':
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
    if not options.data_file:
        parser.print_usage()
        sys.exit(1)

    main(options.data_file, options.cell_sep, options.cell_col_sep)
```